# My website crashes in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, crash

the website http://www.werkenbijlife-mobility.nl/ crashes sometimes in Internet Explorer 8.
I tried to disable some scripts, but that doesn't help.
I also tried to visit the site in IE7 but it seems that it doesn't crash in that browser.

Does anybody know what might be the problem?

ps sorry for my poor English language.

Comment: I've opened it several times with IE8 and it seems to work fine... what do you mean with "it crashes"? Javascript error popup? It doesn't show as expected? The explorer crashes?

Comment: what do you mean with "it crashes"?

Comment: I get a popup with an errorreport. Screeshot: http://www.werkenbijlife-mobility.nl/error.jpg

Comment: If not yet solved this is how I would approach the problem:
Ensure the JS libs are up to date, linted and use tools to debug like Chrome DevTools if any bugs. Or..
Disable JavaScript, if it works then you know it's a problem with your JS,
If it's your JS, comment out every script and remove the comments one by one until you find the conflict. Then in least you've isolated the problem or exposed others. I think it's likely to be a case of updating plugins.